# extracting String from a String

Tags: java, string, extract

I have this String extracted from a body of an e-mail

```
"DESTINATION: 71222222 PRIORITY: urgent AUTRE: rien"
```

I am looking to extract the strings `"71222222"`, `"urgent"` and `"rien"`.

I have tried the class Scanner but it did not work.

Which is the best solution to do it in Java?

Comment: Are there newline at the end of each of them??

Comment: Have a look at [`.split(" ")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: How did you use Scanner? Seems like Scanner could be used for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
String text = "DESTINATION: 71222222 PRIORITY: urgent AUTRE: rien";

String[]lines = text.replace(": ", ":").split(" ");     
String[]values = new String[lines.length];
int i=0;
for(String line : lines){
   values[i++] = line.split(":")[1];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
```

the output is

```
[ 71222222,  urgent,  rien]
```

you can also try this

```
String text = "DESTINATION: 71222222 PRIORITY: urgent AUTRE: rien";

StringTokenizer tokinizer = new StringTokenizer(text,": ");

while(tokinizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    tokinizer.nextToken();  //skip first
    System.out.println(tokinizer.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: the new line may not be guaranteed to be "\n" may be "\r"

Comment: the email string has been changed anyway

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions, like this:

```
String s = "#DESTINATION: 71222222\n"+
    "#PRIORITY: urgent\n"+
    "#AUTRE: rien";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=: )[^ ]+$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

The core of this solution is this regular expression: `(?<=: )[^ ]+$`. It matches a sequence of non-space characters that follow colon+space `": "` sequence all the way to the end of line `$`.

Demo on ideone: [link](http://ideone.com/xTVXO).

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to extract the information you need:

```
final String input = "DESTINATION: 71222222 PRIORITY: urgent AUTRE: rien";

final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\w+: ");

while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

This prints:

```
71222222 
urgent 
rien
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It uses regex to split the string by white space (\s)

```
        String str  = "DESTINATION: 71222222 PRIORITY: urgent AUTRE: rien";
        String[] split = str.split("\\s");
        System.out.println(split[1]+" - "+split[3]+" - "+split[5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction: when the question first came in the input string included line-feeds. It looks like now the question has been edited to remove the line-feeds. If they are no longer there then my solution won't work.

My first thought is to write a parsing routine that creates a map of key/value pairs. Then you can fetch the data pieces by name and the order in the string doesn't matter.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Main
{

    /**
     * This method parses a string of "key:value" pairs into a map. Parameter
     * pairs are separated by new-lines.
     * @param in the string to parse
     * @return the data map
     */
    static Map<String,String> parseParameters(String in) {

        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();

        int pos = 0;
        while(pos<in.length()) {
            int i = in.indexOf("\n",pos);
            if(i<0) i=in.length();
            String sub = in.substring(pos,i);
            pos = i+1;
            int j = sub.indexOf(":");
            if(j>=0) {
                String key = sub.substring(0,j).trim();
                String val = sub.substring(j+1).trim();
                //System.out.println(key+":"+val);
                params.put(key,val);
            }
        }

        return params;
    }

    public static void main( String args[] )
    { 
        String in = "#DESTINATION: 71222222\n#PRIORITY: urgent\n#AUTRE: rien";

        Map<String,String> params = parseParameters(in);

        // Get the data pieces by name
        System.out.println(params.get("#AUTRE"));
        System.out.println(params.get("#DESTINATION"));
        System.out.println(params.get("#PRIORITY"));

    }
}
```